# Android app upgrade hanging when installed from Google Play store

Tags: android

I've encountered a strange issue when my app is upgraded from the Google Play App store.

When I upgrade from the old version to new, my app freezes - no stacktrace, no logs, no errors in logcat for the device, simply the below:

```
03-17 23:48:18.402 24436-24436/? W/My App: Upgrading database - data will be transferred
03-17 23:48:21.221 4519-9571/? I/TaskMonitor: Top activity component: ComponentInfo{com.test.myApp/com.test.myApp.Launch} lookup 3ms, sleep 140788280ms
03-17 23:48:49.117 3344-3359/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{24a1830 u0 com.test.myApp/.Launch t11658}
03-17 23:48:59.119 3344-3359/? W/ActivityManager: Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{24a1830 u0 com.test.myApp/.Launch t11658}
```

The last log my app outputs is from my database class (onUpgrade):

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("My App", "Upgrading database - data will be transferred");

        //RULES UPDATE
        try {
            Log.w("My App", "Creating temporary Rules table...");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Rules_new (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, RuleName TEXT, RuleAlertFilter TEXT, RuleCriteria TEXT, RuleProfile TEXT, RuleEnabled BOOLEAN, RuleVibrate BOOLEAN, RuleVibratePattern TEXT, RuleAudio BOOLEAN, RuleAudioFile TEXT, RuleAppList TEXT)");
            Log.w("My App", "Temporary Rules table created.");
            Log.w("My App", "Creating temporary Filter table...");
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Filters_new (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FilterType TEXT, FilterCriteriaType TEXT, FilterCriteria TEXT, FilterRuleID INTEGER)");
            Log.w("My App", "Temporary Filter table created.");
        }
        catch(SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.w("My App", "Error creating new tables: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        Log.w("My App", "New tables created");

if(oldVersion<2) {
    //migration from v1-v2
.......
```

As you can see, the next log line is to output the text "Creating temporary Rules table.." however this never gets output.

I have done some further testing and found that the upgrade is successful when upgrading from prod version in the Google Play store to the latest apk manually on the device (the same one uploaded to the Google Play store for beta testing).

Comment: are you using the app in offline mode(i.e. without internet connection) and using crashlytics?

Comment: Hi, I've always been online when testing. I've not used crashlytics.

Comment: Interestingly, if I edit the log output "Upgrading database" to anything else, rebuild it and deploy it, it never changed. I've tried cleaning the project and recompiling a release build, but it is as if it never gets updated. I have noticed an older version than the one I have uploaded is actually installed (e.g. I set the new version to 2.0.0.1, built the signed SDK and uploaded, but when I upgrade to this version in the Google Play Store is seems to be installing 2.0.0.0 instead).

Comment: assuming that you are increasing DB version and app version (in build gradle), but it shouldn't be accepted on play console if the app have the same version which is published on play store. You can test app before publishing it to play store, just download the latest version from play store and create a signed apk and install it.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go. I was upgrading the DB version and app version in the AndroidManifest file, I'll also have a look in the build gradle. You are correct, on occasion I have forgot to increment the version number and the console complained - however, even after incrementing it the version installed is still 2.0.0.0 and not 2.0.0.1. I will try and install the current prod version and try sideloading the signed APK for 2.0.0.1 and see if that works later today.